# Any dynamic database frontend tool from which you can update directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, frontend

This is with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081522/mysql-scenario-get-all-tasks-even-if-there-is-no-entry/2100759#2100759) where I got one tabular report format.

I need to update the user entered values correctly back to the same table rows. I am in the process of doing this by using general form post data methods by using some logics which I think will not be easy to maintain. So, just out of curiosity, Is there a front end creator javascript libraries or frameworks which can create the front end for any query's resultset and updates the corresponding rows when the user updates them from front end. This need not have all the full functionality, any one usable, customizable thing will reduce the code maintenance problems. I have googled for some javascript libraris for this but not able to get which will be suitable. Please suggest any useful tools. My environment is Mysql, PHP, JQuery, XAMPP server on Windows. Is JQuery provides one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok if not for a query resultset, at least for a particular table, is there a frontend generator which can do the same.

Comment: Mysql front works in simialr way but only for one target table (not on query result set) as you all mentioned. And we know of Phpmyadmin as admin tool but we wanted to give this front end to users which is not possible through phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*...from any query's resultset...*"  I suspect there is no tool that can do that.  Imagine a resultset of data from a table with one (or more) columns which has a foreign key to another table(s).  A tool would need to find the relationship between the tables, update the "lookup table", and then update the dependent table.  Now imagine a more complicated resultset from a variety of tables - maybe some of those tables are views.  Tall order...

I use phpMyAdmin to update tables in my schema, but I perform these updates as an admin rather than a user.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the nature of the app nor do i know of any JS libraries with this type of functionality. I think i would look at PHP libraries/components as opposed to JS. For example Symfony could lend you this functionality through the use of its admin generator features. While converting something youre well along on to Symfony for the sake of admin generation probably isnt the best idea, i think youre bound to find alo tmore resources on the server side than the client side. :-)